# After install grunt url not working?

Tags: angularjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtA6Q.png)Am install AngularJS Development with Yeoman, Grunt and Bower install complete successfully,and then run server using grunt server it's also running successfully, but my url passing like below,

```
http://localhost:9010/#!/#%2F
http://localhost:9010/#!/#%2Fabout
http://localhost:9010/#!/#%2F
```

Once click about,contact link not working passing url like above,it's not getting about,contact page is there any problem in my installation process or anything changed in files please give me solution.

```
'use strict';


  angular
.module('newangularApp', [
'ngAnimate',
'ngCookies',
'ngResource',
'ngRoute',
'ngSanitize',
'ngTouch'
])
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'main'
  })
  .when('/about', {
    templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
    controller: 'AboutCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'about'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
 });

 (function(window, angular) {'use strict';


    function shallowCopy(src, dst) {
    if (isArray(src)) {
 dst = dst || [];

for (var i = 0, ii = src.length; i < ii; i++) {
  dst[i] = src[i];
}
} else if (isObject(src)) {
dst = dst || {};

for (var key in src) {
  if (!(key.charAt(0) === '$' && key.charAt(1) === '$')) {
    dst[key] = src[key];
  }
     }
     }

 return dst || src;
  }
  var ngRouteModule = angular.
  module('ngRoute', []).
   provider('$route', $RouteProvider).
 // Ensure `$route` will be instantiated in time to capture the initial `$locationChangeSuccess`
  // event (unless explicitly disabled). This is necessary in case `ngView` is included in an
   // asynchronously loaded template.
  run(instantiateRoute);
   var $routeMinErr = angular.$$minErr('ngRoute');
   var isEagerInstantiationEnabled;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtA6Q.png)

Comment: Show your route script.

Comment: Check above route script code,ng-route install bower

Comment: Use `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`  below your routes.

Comment: Error: [$location:nobase] $location in HTML5 mode requires a <base> tag to be present!
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$location/nobase got error like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable `html5Mode` in your code.

```
.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'main'
  })
  .when('/about', {
    templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
    controller: 'AboutCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'about'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
 });
```

Now remove `#` from your anchoring elements(`<a>`). This will solve your problem.

In head section add `<base href="/">` of index.html

Comment: $locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: true,
  requireBase: false
}); add this comment,but url for about and content like,http://localhost:9010/#%2F

Comment: Don't understand what you are saying exactly.

Comment: My problem is  About content page not loading,My url Slash passing %2F like this.

Comment: this solution is work for me. you save my day @Sai. just need little explanation why we need base href in head section? and global test i have same issue like you mentioned in your question just follow the instructions. just add $locationProvider, remove # sign from urls and define base href in head section.

Comment: ya @sai working me too thanq so much Am forgot to remove # from a tag,Now working.